# Does "differentiability implies continuity" not apply for piecewise functions?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I always thought that a function had to be continuous to be differentiable - so this problem is a bit confusing to me:

> Find A and B so the derivative of $ f(x) $ exists everywhere.

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 3Bx+4A-ln(2x-7)&\text{for}\, x\leq 4\\
 12A\sqrt x+3Bx+4A&\text{for}\, x> 4\\
\end{cases}
$

Finding the derivatives of each piece and setting them equal to each other indicates that $ A = -2/3 $. However, the original function is not continuous when $ A = -2/3 $. In order for the original function to be continuous, $ A = 0 $.

Does "differentiability implies continuity" not apply for piecewise functions?

Comment: Yes, you need continuity for differentiability.  As written, this problem has no solution.  But also, it looks like $B$ doesn’t matter, since it’s the same on both sides.  Are you sure this is copied correctly?  With one plus sign changed to a minus, there would be a unique solution.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, I've double checked that it was copied correctly. I was reviewing an old test from my calculus 1 course and this was a problem on it. On the test, I wrote that A=-2/3 and received full credit for the question and the professor didn't write any comments.

Comment: Differentiability always implies continuity. However, when differentiating piecewise functions, you can only differentiate on open intervals. The function you provided is not differentiable at $4$ because it is not continuous at $4.$ To prove it is not differentiable at $4,$ you *must* use the definition of the derivative. Simply differentiating the first case does not give you the derivative at $4,$ because that is not how differentiation of piecewise functions works.

Comment: @Angel Why do you claim that it is not continuous at $4$? It is continuous at $4$ if and only if $A=0$.

Comment: In other words, given your definition of $f,$ the only thing you can say is that $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}3B-\frac{2}{2x-7}&x\lt4\\\frac{6A}{\sqrt{x}}+3B&x\gt4\end{cases}.$$ For $x=4,$ whether $f$ is differentiable or not must be checked separately using the definition of the derivative. It could have turned out to be differentiable there, but in this case, it is not.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I was referring to the case with $A=-2/3.$ I should have been more clear, though.

Comment: It should be noted that continuity does not imply differentiability. So the fact that $f$ is continuous at $4$ when $A=0$ does not mean it should also be differentiable there as well. So this is not an issue with piecewise functions, so much as it confusing "continuity implies differentiability" with "differentiability implies continuity." The latter is always true, but not the former.

Comment: Continuity at $x = 4$ requires $4 A+12 B = 28 A+12 B$.  Differentiability at $x = 4$ requires both $4 A+12 B = 28 A+12 B$ and $3B - 2 = 3A + 3B$, which linear system has no solution.  Your $A = -2/3$ (satisfying only the second equation) forces $\lim_{x \rightarrow 4^-} f'(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 4^+} f'(x)$, but this is not enough to show $f'(4)$ exists.  (Edit: forgot the primes...)

Comment: @Angel *"It should be noted that continuity does not imply differentiability. So the fact that f is continuous at 4 when A=0 does not mean it should also be differentiable there as well."* yep - that makes sense to me, no issue there :)

Comment: @EricTowers Yeah, what you've stated makes sense to me. So was this just a really bad exam question? And why would I have gotten full credit for writing that A = -2/3?

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit Alright, I understand. Then perhaps the issue has to do with what Eric Towers mentioned in his comment, which relates to what I said in my previous comment: you can only make statements about $f'$ for $x\lt4$ and $x\gt4,$ but not for $x=4,$ which requires using the definition of the derivative.

Comment: It's a perfectly good exam question.  The correct answer is "There is no such pair $A$ and $B$."  I'm reluctant to guess at the mental process a grader went through to assign a grade to your answer.  (Heck, given the number of answers I've graded, it seems likely that I've assigned an incorrect grade a few times just through sheer statistics and the recognition that massive repetition dulls my thinking.)

Comment: @EricTowers Okay that's helpful, thank you. I guess the fact that it was marked correct is what threw me off.